# "Protected sheets and ranges" appears set up OK, but still can't edit

Tags: google-sheets

I am using a shared Google Sheets" that has 2 sheets "Data" and "Codes". Protection was set on certain cells in "Data" and I can edit those without protection. But on the "Codes" sheet, even though protection is only set on "Codes!A1:E16", I still cannot edit any of the other cells in the sheet.

The owner is trying to grant me access to the other cells, but nothing appears to work. I noticed that when I click the down arrow next to the "Data" and the "Codes" sheet tabs at the bottom, that there are many more options available for the Data sheet than the Codes sheet. So they appear to have been set up differently. Is there another place for settings on these sheets, where the permissions could have been set differently?

Comment: Solutions should not be posted as a question edit, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The owner was able to unlock the other cells outside the A1:E16 ranges. He stated that he "removed the legacy protection'. I know there's a "legacy" version of G-Suite the Google phased out, that I have not used. It appears that there is a protection setting on the entire sheet that needed to be undone.